# Why does Analytics Data API V1 Beta not conform to the REST spec?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I'm adding GTM and GA4 to some website apps that need to produce detailed stats on the click-throughs of ads per advertiser.
This looks infeasible with standard GA reporting so am using the PHP implementation of Analytics Data API V1 Beta. Since there are few examples (eg  analyticsdata/quickstart.php)  of V1 reporting using PHP, I am translating other classes and operands from the REST API’s JSON .

```
<?php
namespace Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$property_id = '<redacted>';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=Keyfile.json');

$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

// Make an API call.
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
    
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '2021-04-01',
            'end_date' => 'today',
        ]
        ),
    ],
    'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
        [
           'name' => 'customEvent:link_classes'
        ]
    ),
    ],
        
     'dimensionFilter'=>[new FilterExpression(
           [
           'filter'=>[new Filter(
           [
          'field_name' => 'customEvent:Classes',
          'string_filter' => [new Filter\StringFilter(
          [
          'match_type'=> '1',
          'value'=> 'AdvertA',
          'case_sensitive'=> false 
          ])]])]])],
    
    'metrics' => [new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'eventCount',
        ]
    )
    ]
]);
etc
```

The Quickstart example works but has endless trouble when a *dimensionFilter* is added.
For example, match_type should be an enum of one of a few character strings (EXACT, CONTAINS and so on). The JSON definition of match_type only shows the strings (enum 'members') and not any associated values (which would usually be integers). The GA4 migration guide has an example with

```
 "matchType": "BEGINS_WITH"
```

PHP doesn’t have ‘enum’ but the equivalent would be to select one string and assign it to match_type (vide above). Wrong: StringFilter falls over unless it is given an integer operand, presumably the ordinal number of the desired match in the enum match string (and is the first one 0 or 1?). My understanding of the JSON schema was that an 'enum' list simply restricted the result to one of the unique operands, with an optional check on the operand type. (By comparison, the Python enumerate function returns an object containing a list of pairs with the ordinal number of an operand preceding the operand).

*Custom dimensions* appear not to conform to the API’s JSON. In Analytics, I specify a custom dimension with a dimension Name of Classes and User Property/Parameter of link_classes**.
However...  in the API, dimension Name has to be customEvent:link_classes and not customEvent:Classes. Otherwise it falls over with ‘*Field customEvent:Classes is not a valid dimension*’
This occurs also when defining field_name in a Filter within a Filter Expression.
So is the API dimension Name not the name of the Analytics dimension Name but actually the Property/Parameter of an Analytics descriptive name? In one place I read the latter: "*Custom dimensions are specified in an API report request by the dimension's **parameter name** and scope*." but elsewhere it is implied that Name is the dimension name, e.g. /devguides/reporting/data/v1/advanced:
"**dimensions**": [{ "**name**": "customUser:last_level" }]

Finally, even falling in line with what the developers have implemented, dimensionFilter falls over with ‘*Expect Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter\StringFilter*’

It is Beta code but one would not expect overt deviations from the REST spec so perhaps I am reading the spec wrongly. Does anyone else have this problem?

** GTM has a ‘Click - Just Links’ trigger where the ‘click URL’  ‘contains’ the advertiser’s URL. The Classes custom dimension in the API dimension Filter has the class values of the adverts  click-through links.

Comment: this is a beta api and an alpha library you are using.   Have you tried reporting the bugs?

Comment: Thanks  for that DaimTo. I was under the mistaken impression that the associated PHP class library was Beta and wasn't aware of a difference between the 'API' specific code and the background class library. I believe that my Custom Dimensions issue is simply slack documentation but that the match_type problem is an error. What pls is the best process for reporting bugs to the development team (or is it just the Google Analytics Community ? )

Comment: I have sent your question over to one of the developers at Google.   See if we cant get some of your documentation issues cleaned up.  I can not guarantee that he will respond to your question directly though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, I believe the correct way to use an enum in PHP would be:

> 'match_type' => Filter\StringFilter\MatchType::BEGINS_WITH

As for the second question. Per [the API schema documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#custom_dimensions) the name of a custom dimension is constructed as  `customEvent:parameter_name` for event scoped dimensions and `customUser:parameter_name` for user scoped dimensions.
Where `parameter_name`, as you correctly noted, is not a descriptive name, but rather the event parameter name. In your example you seem to be using a user scoped dimension, so the dimension name in the API should be `customUser:link_classes`.

Here is a complete example that seems to be running fine:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\FilterExpression;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;

/**
 * TODO(developer): Replace this variable with your Google Analytics 4
 *   property ID before running the sample.
 */
$property_id = 'YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID';


$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

// Make an API call.
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '2020-03-31',
            'end_date' => 'today',
        ]),
    ],
    'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
        [
            'name' => 'customUser:link_classes'
        ]),
    ],

    'dimensionFilter' => new FilterExpression(
        [
            'filter' => new Filter(
                [
                    'field_name' => 'customUser:link_classes',
                    'string_filter' => new Filter\StringFilter(
                        [
                            'match_type' => Filter\StringFilter\MatchType::BEGINS_WITH,
                            'value' => 'AdvertA',
                            'case_sensitive' => false
                        ]
                    )
                ])

        ]),

    'metrics' => [new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'eventCount',
        ]
    )
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks Ilya for a most useful, prompt and correct reply.
Three points:

**1.**
Using

```
'match_type' => Filter\StringFilter\MatchType::BEGINS_WITH
```

instead of:

```
'match_type' => ‘BEGINS_WITH’
```

fixes the problem of “Uncaught Exception: Expect integer. in /vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/GPBUtil.php” as the
MatchType::BEGINS_WITH (etc) constant *returns* an integer (in this case 2) from class MatchType.

**2.**
It would forestall errors if a reminder were added to the places in Custom Dimension documentation where dimension Name is used, such as
/devguides/reporting/data/v1/advanced: "dimensions": [{ "name": "customUser:last_level" }]
emphasising that name is not the dimension Name as defined to Analytics but rather the associated User Property/Parameter name. Or perhaps the Name heading in GA's Custom Dimension 'form' should be amended.

**3.**
Finally, dimensionFilter falling over with

```
 ‘Expect Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter\StringFilter’
```

error message was caused by my stupidity in instantiating FilterExpression, Filter and StringFilter as if they were array elements,
e.g

```
'string_filter' => [new Filter\StringFilter(
```

rather than

```
'string_filter' => new Filter\StringFilter(
```

something that is an unfortunately easy mistake to make when carelessly following the sample report code, where dateRanges, dimensions and so on correctly define arrays (since they can take multiple date ranges and dimensions), e.g.

```
   'dimensions' => [new Dimension (
```